# merge multiple xml

Tags: xml

I have Googled, and looked everywhere.
Im searching for a simple PHP script like PHP DOM with 2 functions:
Merge multiple RSS/XML feed without changing the nodes, scheme etc.
Sort them out by pubDate.

So it doesn't need XSL to change the XML scheme or anything, just merge multiple XML to one and sort them out by pubdate.

Answer (score 1):

A little Googling [showed one possible solution in PHP](http://www.russellbeattie.com/blog/merging-feeds-using-phps-dom).  It doesn't do the sort by pubdate, but that shouldn't be too hard to do.